# can't sync data between 2 component in real time

Tags: angular

I have 2 different angular components, one for adding data into database which is a non real time database, and the other is for retrieving those data, the problem is when I want to add data in the first component while calling saveData() in the service then it will add it to the array of data which I have when I call getData() in the same service and then call if from getData component and then display it automatically without refreshing, here is my code:

**store.service.ts:**

```
storeChanged = new Subject<Store[]>()
    baseUrl = 'MyURL';
    store: Store[];
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    getData() {
        return this.http.get<Store[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/store.php`, {
            observe: 'body',
            responseType: 'json'
        }).subscribe((response) => { 
            this.store= response['data'];
    })}
  saveData(store) {
         return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/createStore.php`, store)
            .subscribe((store) => {
                    this.store.push(store['data']);
  })}
```

**store.component.ts**

```
subscription: Subscription;
  store: Store[];
  constructor(private storeService: storeService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.storeService.getData();
  }
```

any help would be appreciated!

**Edited**

**addFeatures.component.ts**

```
 store: Store;
  id: number;
  constructor(private storeService: storeServiceService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) =>
      {
        this.id = +params['id'];
        this.getStoreById(this.id);
      }
    );
  }

  getStoreById = (id) => {
    this.storeService.getStoreById(id).subscribe(response => this.store = 
    response);
  }
```

and then I'll map my store in the template with *ngFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change`store: Store[]` to an observable by doing:

```
store: Observable<Store[]> = this.storeChanged.asObservable();
```

In the `getData()` method:

```
...
.subscribe((response) => { 
    this.storeChanged.next(response['data']);
 })}
```

In the `saveData()` method:

```
...
 .subscribe((store) => {
     this.storeChanged.next([...this.storeChanged.getValue(),store['data']]);
  })}
```

And in **store.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.storeService.store.subscribe(response => this.store = response);
    this.storeService.getData();
  }
```

Hope that helps

**UPDATE**

In order to use `getValue()`, you need to change `storeChanged` to `BehaviorSubject` and pass it an initial value.

```
storeChanged: BehaviorSubject<Store[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you want to retrieve a single item with a method that return an `Observable`

```
getStoreByID = (id): Observable<Store> => {
    return this.storeChaged.pipe(map( storeArr => storeArr.find(item => item.id === id)))
}
```

And in the component:

```
getStoreByID = (id) => {
    this.storeService.getStoreByID(id).subscribe(response => this.store = response)
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response, but getValue() does not exist on type Subject<store[]>

Comment: Edited the answer. Please have a look at the updated section

Comment: what if I want to retrieve a single element in the array of objects in a method called getStoreById(id) where there is another component is calling this method, then how could we access to the values of retrieved of the retrieved data?

Comment: Edited the answer again. Please have a look

Comment: If you provide me your code in stackblitz or somewhere alike, I can help you further.

Comment: [Here is the stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1mp7ug).